# AngularJS CSS3 Animations for ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs

My CSS is:

```
.fade-in-repeat {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}​

/* Opera */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}​
```

My HTML is:

```
  <tr class="fade-in-repeat" ng-repeat="transaction in transactions | orderBy:transaction.time">
    <td>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
```

So as items are added, I want them to fade in. The problem is there is a [FUOC](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flash%20of%20unstyled%20content) before the animation kicks in, which makes it look like it's flickering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `opacity:0` to `.fade-in-repeat`'s  CSS

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Le2ad/)